# How can I install xdebug?

Tags: php, xdebug

I want to install xdebug.I am facing problem regarding it. I have download dll file for xdebug. When i was install xdebug the `phpinfo();` not displaying that xdebug. So anyone can help me to do this. i have also edit php.ini file after placed xdebug.dll file in ext folder.
and is that necessary to install zend for use the xdebug?
So please help

```
[XDebug] 
;zend_extension = "C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug.dll" 
;xdebug.profiler_append = 0 ;xdebug.profiler_enable = 1 
;xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = 0 
;xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "C:\xampp\tmp" 
;xdebug.profiler_output_name = "cachegrind.out.%t-%s" 
;xdebug.remote_enable = 0 
;xdebug.remote_handler = "dbgp" 
;xdebug.remote_host = "127.0.0.1" 
;xdebug.trace_output_dir = "C:\xampp\tmp"
```

and i have install xdebug.dll file here: `C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug.dll`

Comment: Post your php.ini file and the location where you "installed" which file.

Comment: php.ini file has this content about xdebug


[XDebug]
;zend_extension = "C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug.dll"
;xdebug.profiler_append = 0
;xdebug.profiler_enable = 1
;xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = 0
;xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "C:\xampp\tmp"
;xdebug.profiler_output_name = "cachegrind.out.%t-%s"
;xdebug.remote_enable = 0
;xdebug.remote_handler = "dbgp"
;xdebug.remote_host = "127.0.0.1"
;xdebug.trace_output_dir = "C:\xampp\tmp"

Comment: and i have install xdebug.dll file here C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug.dll here

Comment: ALWAYS add additional information and details to the question itself, there is an `edit` option up there. Otherwise people have to collect all those bits of information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aparently you did not enable the debugger:

Note all those `;` characters at the beginning of your entries in the [`XDEBUG]` section of your `php.ini` file. They mark that line as a comment, as *not* active. So in the end you did add a section, but without any active entries!

Remove (some of) these semicolons as mentioned in all manuals. Then test again by calling your phpinfo script!

Comment: Bro i have remove comment but that also not help.Apache 2.4 php-5.4.7 and i am trying to install xdebug version php_xdebug-2.2.3-5.3-vc9-nts-x86_64 so is this correct or version problem?

Comment: What appears in the apache error log file when you restart the daemon? Either you get a hint there (like some incompatibility) or your php.ini file is not read (wrong file, maybe there are different versions in different locations on your system).

Comment: So most likely you changed the wrong `php.ini` file. Have a try making a syntax error in there by purpose: Above the `[XDebug]` section enter some line line `* * * __=sdf sfdg ??` (something that does not make sense, a syntax error) and restart the http daemon again. Dies it complain about the line? If not, then you proved that it is the wrong `php.ini` file. Also: did you _really_ ( I mean _REALLY_) restart the http daemon after changing the file?

Comment: i have three php.ini file.
php.ini,php.ini(INI-DEVELOPMENT),php.ini(INI-PRODUCTION)
Can you say that which file i have to edit?

Comment: i had tried by edit this three php.ini file and add this code for start xdebug but not getting any output

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea about the type or layout of your system, nor do I recognize those terms you specify in brackets. But the `phpinof()` output actually states which files have been processed during startup. That should bring you on the right track...